# Equal bar width across facet_wrap barplots

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a data frame that looks like this:

```
category = c(rep("house", 2), rep("apartment", 4), rep("condo", 3))
sample = paste("ID", seq(1:9), sep='')
group = c(rep(1,9), rep(2,9))
value = c(0.990000, 0.608143, 0.451284, 0.500343, 0.482670, 0.358965, 0.393272, 0.300472, 0.334363, 0.001000, 0.391857, 0.548716, 0.499657, 0.517330, 0.641035, 0.606728, 0.699528, 0.665637)
data = as.data.frame(cbind(category, sample, group, value))
```

I want to use the variable 'category' to facet_wrap a stacked barplot, like this:

```
ggplot(data, aes(x=sample, y=value, fill=group)) + 
  geom_bar(stat="identity", width=1) +
  facet_wrap(facet ~ ., scales="free_x")
```

The number of samples in each category is uneven but ggplot automatically makes each barplot the same width, meaning that the bars across plots are not the same width, like this:

[image]

Is there a way to force ggplot to keep the bars all the same width, such that the overall width of each barplot is different across plots?

Thanks for any tips!

Comment: It is not exactly clear to me what output you are looking for? Can you explain?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try `facet_grid`

```
ggplot(data, aes(x = sample, y = value, fill = group)) + 
    geom_bar(stat = "identity", width = 1, col = "black") +
    facet_grid(. ~ category, scales = "free", space = "free")
```

Comment: thanks for the suggestion @d.b that solved my issue!